# AD2 waveforms oscilloscope data logging question

Tags: oscilloscope, waveform

Does anyone know a good way to log oscilloscope data for a specified time duration using Waveforms software and an AD2?

I am trying to read a raw signal with the oscilloscope function in [Waveforms](https://digilent.com/shop/software/digilent-waveforms/) using an [Analog Discovery 2 (AD2)](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/d/digilent/analog-discovery-2). I know there is a way to log the data via exporting but this only logs what is immediately on the screen (and always 8192 samples). Instead I am looking to capture voltage measurements for a specified duration of time (about 30 seconds) and save this to a csv file.

I know one way that can approach this would be to change the time/div in the horizontal axis so that a longer time span is covered, but this reduces the temporal resolution/decreases sampling frequency which isn't ideal for my application.

P.S. I have tried using code to connect to the com port of the device and save the data coming from there directly to a csv file, but this doesn't work.